# I am getting null pointer exception because not able to initialize List

Tags: json, wrapper-class

I am getting null pointer exception when adding referral data in List. I am not getting how to initialize List inside Messages class.

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Messages {
        public List<Referral> Referral;
    }

    public String SourceSystem;
    public String MessageVersion;
    public Messages Messages;

    public class Referral {
        public MetaData MetaData;
        public Integer Budget;
        public String budgetCurrency;
        public String city;
        public String companyMdmId;
        public String companyName;
    }

    public class MetaData {
        public String Guid;
        public String MessageOperation;
        public String Country;
        public String BusinessLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inline initializer:

```
public class Messages {
    public List<Referral> Referral = new List<Referral>();
}
```

Note that while deserializing a JSON string, if the property is missing or null, it will still be a null value.